# UITextview not getting completely filled with the text in IPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview

In my app, I have a `UITextView`. When I key in data in the `UITextView`, the words are not getting completely filled in the `UITextview`. There is a boundary within the `UITextView` and the words scroll up as I key in the words. Is there a setting which I am missing in `UITextView`. Please let me know. Please  find the screenshot below

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure if I got your question correctly but you can set a frame and a `contentSize` as it inherits from the `UIScrollView` to make it bigger

Comment: Thanks. To rephrase the question, when I continue key in words into UITextview after 4 lines when I type into the fifth line, the first line scrolls up. There comes a invisible boundary at the 5th line and when I key in more text, say when I am in the 6th line, the second line scrolls up and become invisible. Can you please help me in how to remove this boundary and make the texts fill the UITextview.

Comment: I could help you with this by improving my answer if only you paste a code how you set this currently

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a frame and a `contentSize` as it inherits from the `UIScrollView` to make it bigger. I do not have access to IDE right now but something like this should work:

```
myTextView.frame = CGRectMake(10,10,300,300);//example values
myTextView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(300,300);//example values
```

but sooner or later you want be able to see the whole text on the screen and you will need to scroll anyway.

You can also change this values while user is typing by using some [delegate methods](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITextViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UITextViewDelegate.html)